# ¿Cómo deserializar todos los datos de un archivo .ser en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, javafx, java-8, serialización

Serializar me guarda todos los datos en un archivo receta.ser osea si parece que funciona correctamente, el problema es en deserializar, quiero que me traiga todos los datos guardados en el archivo receta.ser y me imprima toda la lista o array de datos.

```
//Serializar
public  Serializar(Receta d) {
    FileOutputStream file = null;

    try {

        file = new FileOutputStream("receta.ser,true");
        ObjectOutputStream salidadoc = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
        salidadoc.writeObject(d);
        salidadoc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
//Deserializar
try(ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("receta.ser"))){
         while(true){
             Receta aux = (Receta)ios.readObject();
             System.out.println(aux.getCodigo());
             System.out.println(aux.getNumtratamientos());
             
         }
     }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
     }catch(EOFException e){
     }catch(IOException e){
     }
```

Comment: El archivo que se está generando no tiene como nombre `receta.ser,true`? Y luego se intenta abrir como `receta.ser`

Answer (score 1):

El problema se encuentra al crear el archivo, debes usar el constructor

> ```
> FileOutputStream(archivo de archivo, anexo booleano)
> ```
>
> Cree una secuencia de salida de archivo para escribir en el archivo
> representado por el objeto File especificado.

Ya que lo que estas realizando es crear un archivo con el nombre `"receta.ser,true"`, debes cambiar tu còdigo, para crear el archivo `receta.ser` y poder deserializarlo:

```
   try {
        // file = new FileOutputStream("receta.ser,true");
        file = new FileOutputStream("receta.ser",true);
        ObjectOutputStream salidadoc = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
        salidadoc.writeObject(d);
        salidadoc.close();
    }
```

Revisa la documentaciòn:

[FileOutputStream​(File file, boolean append)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean))